# How to do the multiplication with array objects

Tags: javascript

How to do the multiplication with array objects and get the all 3 outputs

```js
const size = [
  { hight: 20, width: 23, length: 54 },
  { hight: 40, width: 43, length: 44 },
  { hight: 20, width: 23, length: 54 },
];
const total = (size) => {
  const totalvalue = size.hight * size.width * size.length;
};    
console.log(total)
```

Comment: What's the expected result?

Comment: You are not calling total. Size is an array, you will need to use size[0], size[1], size[i]

Comment: And you're also not returning anything from the function that you're not calling.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#parameters).

```js
const size = [
  { hight: 20, width: 23, length: 54 },
  { hight: 40, width: 43, length: 44 },
  { hight: 20, width: 23, length: 54 },
];

 const total = (size) => {
  const totalvalue = size.hight * size.width * size.length;
  return totalvalue; 
};

console.log(size.map(total))
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to loop through the array. Something like:

```js
const size = [
    { hight: 20, width: 23, length: 54 },
    { hight: 40, width: 43, length: 44 },
    { hight: 20, width: 23, length: 54 },
];
const total = row => row.total = row.hight + row.width + row.length;
size.forEach(total);

console.log(size);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can make use of the reduce function

```
var sum = array.reduce(function(pv, cv) { return pv + cv; }, 0);
```

Link to follow https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce